# reverse engineering Hive rank/dense_rank function - how hive implements rank/dense_rank function

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, bigdata, ranking

Does anyone know how the implementation looks like? I have a guess; please correct me if I'm wrong:

```
select
   ENAME,SAL,dense_rank() over (order by SAL) DEN_RANK
from
EMP;
```

Supposing hive is doing a bunch of map and reducers the data will be at some point sorted by `SAL`, right?. However, data might be big enough to be spread across multiple HDFS blocks (each one of them will be sorted, yes). I assume that hive rank/dense_rank manages the HDFS blocks iteration so that it visits each row of a block one followed by the other (in order) in a way that the rank order is respected. Is that assumption correct?

Comment: Hive is Open Source, so why don't you just inspect the source code (under `apache` umbrella)?

Comment: Note that the concept of "HDFS block" has little meaning for columnar format (Parquet, ORC) and even less for files stored on cloud BLOB storage (S3 etc.)

Comment: HDFS blocks (for text files unless GZipped), or ORC/Parquet internal stripes, or entire files (for S3 storage or un-splittable compression codecs) are the boundaries for **mapper** parallelism, in MapReduce. In your query there is no way to parallelize **reducers** 
 hence every single record will have to be sorted again in a single, massive reducer (after the initial parallel reading/filtering/pre-sorting phase in mappers). Using Tez instead of MR will cache the results of one of the mappers when reusing it for the reduce step, but that's no fundamental change, just a marginal optimization

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion: https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/f37c5de6c32b9395d1b34fa3c02ed06d1bfbf6eb/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDAFRank.java this is the link to the rank implementation

Comment: You may also find it useful to use `explain select ...` to review query's logical and physical plans.